# Porting SetTimer() and KillTimer() to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, timer

I am trying to port some code from C++ to C#.

I came across this in the C++ code:

```
watchdogTimer = SetTimer(1,1000,NULL);
...
KillTimer(watchdogTimer);
```

What is this code doing, and how can this be ported to C#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CWnd::SetTimer` function you're looking at creates a timer that sends `WM_TIMER` events to the window. This is analogous to the [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) component in .NET. It behaves somewhat differently than the `System.Timers.Timer`. There are two differences that are particularly relevant:

`Windows.Forms.Timer` calls the event handler on the UI thread. By default, `System.Timers.Timer` calls the event handler on a threadpool thread. You can use [SynchronizingObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx) property to have the `System.Timers.Timer` call on the UI thread.

Another difference is that it's not possible to encounter reentrancy problems with the Windows Forms timer because Windows won't allow multiple `WM_TIMER` messages from the same timer in the queue, nor will it place a `WM_TIMER` message in the queue if one is already being processed. This is generally a good thing.

`System.Timers.Timer`, on the other hand, will allow reentrancy. So if your timer event handler takes longer than the timer period, you can be processing multiple events for the same timer concurrently. If your timer period is 100 ms and processing takes 150 ms, you're going to get another notification while you're processing the first one. If you use the `SynchronizingObject` to force the callback on the UI thread, this can lead to a whole bunch of pending callbacks being queued.

The implementation of the two timers is quite different. The Windows Forms timer uses old style [Windows timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632592%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) that have been around for 20 years. This type of timer requires a window handle and a message loop, and is therefore used only in GUI programs. `System.Timers.Timer` is a thin wrapper around `System.Threading.Timer`, which uses the Windows [Thread Pool Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686271%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the more in-depth answer Jim.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your application is written under MFC, the SetTimer() method belongs to class CWnd and is responsible for setting up a windows timer.  Documentation for this can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49313fdf(v=vs.80).aspx.  I know little about .NET but a quick google search located the following this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcs6ww8(v=VS.90).aspx.

Comment: Thanks Jon. After checking out those pages I think a System.Timers.Timer would do the trick. Pls correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Ryan, just using `System.Timers.Timer` is pretty much all you should need. It would be a very unusual case where you needed to actually set up a window timer yourself.